# Performance testing on Selenium script using JMeter-Junit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I had a selenium-Webdriver script with me, and I wanted to perform Load testing on the script using JMeter.
So What I have done is,
1) I have Exported selenium script into JMeter/Lib/Junit folder.
2) Configured JMeter with JUnit and Marked it to RUN.

**But, am receiving following error in Sample Request :**

> Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1 Sample Start: 2015-04-29 14:48:38 IST
>   Load time: 17190 Latency: 0 Size in bytes: 0 Headers size in bytes: 0
>   Body size in bytes: 0 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1 Response code:
>   1000

**and Log Viewer :**

> 2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine:
>   Running the test!  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []  2015/04/29
>   14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of
>   sample_variables: []  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)  2015/04/29
>   14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting
>   ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group
>   Thread Group.  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
>   2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting
>   thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0
>   delayedStart=false  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see
>   jmeter.properties)  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
>   2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread
>   group number 1  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been
>   started  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread started: Thread Group 1-1  2015/04/29 14:48:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor
>   with one String parameter returned error:
>   Jmetersmaple.(java.lang.String)  2015/04/29 14:48:55 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
>   2015/04/29 14:48:55 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-1  2015/04/29 14:48:55 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of
>   test  2015/04/29 14:48:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar:
>   setRunning(false,*local*)

Can anyone please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't selected your test class and method combination. My expectation is that you're running `test.AfterAnnotatedTest -> afterTest` method.

1. Make sure that you restart JMeter after dropping your JUnit tests .jar file(s) to /lib/junit folder
2. Make sure to add all dependent jars to JMeter classpath as well.
3. Make sure that "Search for JUnit 4 annonations" box corresponds to your JUnit version
4. Make sure that your test class and method(s) are available in dropdowns as JMeter provides a number of pre-defined JUnit tests for reference.
5. See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide for more information on JUnit/JMeter integration.

Comment: Hello Dmitri, I had followed all the steps mentioned,  but still resulting same error. + I had selected proper combination of Class and Method even.

Comment: Can you update the question with JUnit class code and screenshot of JUnit Request sampler?  It's quite hard to tell what's wrong without seeing it